# Reliable Excel API for handling complex Excel report (parsing & writing ~10,000 lines) that works with Java

Tags: java, excel, parsing, jsp, maven-2

i know some similar question already exists, but I haven't found any satisfying answer yet.

I found several library such as Apache POI and JExcelAPI, however as I don't have any previous experience with any Java Excel API yet, perhaps some of you guys who experienced it before can enlighten me regarding the advantages and disadvantages of each API. My requirements are reliability and ease-of-use, because I have to parse and write numerous excel reports with ~10,000 lines in each file.

I'm also considering JXLS which can parse and write document using template to minimize coding effort, but based on my test, we have to hard-code the startRow and endRow when parsing (the startRow and endRow for my document is different for each file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, even the old versions of POI will support 10,000 rows - the limitation was either ~32000 or ~64000 rows.

But the latest POI supports the XML file formats for 2007, and therefore I'm sure memory will be your only limitation.

I use POI in a corporate application, and I've never had a problem with it.

Comment: I second it. I have used POI for an application which also involved heavy excel sheet manipulations. Works like a charm!

Comment: I know it's been a month after i posted this question, but i just want to let you guys know that in the end I use POI and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

[Aspose.Cells for Java](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.cells-for-java/default.aspx) allows you to [create or parse large Excel files in Java](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.cells-for-java/index.html) applications. The API is simple along with complete documentation and support. A large number of users have already incorporated it in their applications. It is easy to learn and any questions can be answered quickly through our support forum. You may try this and see if it helps in your scenario.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score -1):

I've used JExcel with great success, although I can't say that any of those files were on the order of 10,000 rows per file.

I'd wonder if you'd be better off with a relational database with this volume of data.  Excel might have been a fine way to start, but maybe it's time to ask yourself if you've outgrown spreadsheets.

Comment: JExcel seems to only work up to Office 2003.I think giovanni is looking to generate reports and parse excel sheets, I guess for people who use spreadsheets regularly.

Comment: I don't see any mention of which version is being used.  "Seems to work"?  Did you test it with a later version and find that it failed?  as for the rest, I get it.  I don't think this deserves a down vote.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the requirement comes from my client as they wants to migrate their ancient data to relational database.